# Building Container using Dockerfile Plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Follow this article [Build Containers](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers), I try to execute this code on Jenkinsfile, to my suprise, I didnt believe which it would work, but at the end, my container was stopped an removed...

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container 10f1790a9e048db8a874bede30946a607fb5c0ea4c060f177da12c9fe1328d43
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/mobile --volumes-from 10f1790a9e048db8a874bede30946a607fb5c0ea4c060f177da12c9fe1328d43 -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** my-image:6 cat
$ docker top 0bf03e000c2832cc06a270360c8744308ed81d43f36fd297ee286df5dbb3cb4b -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ make test
make: *** No rule to make target 'test'.  Stop.
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 0bf03e000c2832cc06a270360c8744308ed81d43f36fd297ee286df5dbb3cb4b
$ docker rm -f 0bf03e000c2832cc06a270360c8744308ed81d43f36fd297ee286df5dbb3cb4b
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
Finished: FAILURE
```

How is possible the keep the container running using pipeline, kind I'm lost. Any suggest?

```
node {
    checkout scm

    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")

    customImage.inside {
        sh 'make test'
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your current pipeline code look like?  The Jenkins Docker support is a little more designed around using Docker as part of your build-and-test sequence; it isn't designed to start long-running containers on the Jenkins workers.

Comment: My bad, I posted the pipeline code. So, for design that I would like to do, is it not possible? Jenkins Container build and running another containers which is running webapplication